# install git on RHEL3

Tags: redhat, git

having a problem installing git on redhat enterprise 3.  When I try and install the rpm it gives a circular dependency problem.

```
[root@tflaus001 tmp]# rpm -i git-1.5.2.1-1.el3.rf.i386.rpm
warning: git-1.5.2.1-1.el3.rf.i386.rpm: V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 6b8d79e6
error: Failed dependencies:
    perl(Git) is needed by git-1.5.2.1-1.el3.rf


[root@tflaus001 tmp]# rpm -i perl-Git-1.5.2.1-1.el3.rf.i386.rpm
warning: perl-Git-1.5.2.1-1.el3.rf.i386.rpm: V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 6b8d79e6
error: Failed dependencies:
    git = 1.5.2.1-1.el3.rf is needed by perl-Git-1.5.2.1-1.el3.rf
    perl(Error) is needed by perl-Git-1.5.2.1-1.el3.rf
```

can anyone give me an idea of how to fix this or what I need to add to yum.conf to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install both at the same time, i.e.

```
rpm -i git-1.5.2.1-1.el3.rf.i386.rpm perl-Git-1.5.2.1-1.el3.rf.i386.rpm
```

An alternative is to use `yum localinstall some-package-...rpm` where yum will resolve and download any missing dependencies (but in this case you do not need that since you obviously have the two packages you need already).

Answer (score 0):

```
# rpm -ivh git-1.5.2.1-1.el3.rf.i386.rpm perl-Git-1.5.2.1-1.el3.rf.i386.rpm
```

or you can install [DAG repo](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/)  yum install git*

[yum install rhel 3 how to](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/PackageManagement/YumOnRHEL)